# Multiple Monitors on One Screen

Tags: video, multiple-monitors

Does anyone know of any software/hardware configuration that will allow you to preview/view the contents multiple monitors on one monitor? Let's pretend:

1. I have two monitors hooked up to one pc, Monitor A and Monitor B. The monitors are not near each other.
2. I'd like to be able to preview/see what's displaying on Monitor B on Monitor A

I haven't been able to find much about this, but I imagine it may not currently be possible to access/emulate video output going out of a video port in *software*.

However, wouldn't it be possible to capture display data generated by the OS kernel or data getting passed down to the display adapter driver?

Comment: I'd love to know if this is possible. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that accomplishes this task is to run a VNC server on the pc with multiple monitors, then connect to that pc using a VNC Client(that connects to the VNC server running on localhost) on the same pc.

I tested this with a couple VNC servers, and got good results with [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com).

I also created a guide with instructions and screenshots: [Multiple Monitors on One Screen](http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/59-multiple-monitors-on-one-screen)

Comment: Very cool! With the standard zoom feature, VNC naturally solves this problem, even though it's not designed for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you are running the video (svideo, vga, hdmi) you could simply split the video and run one into its designated monitor and the other into a video switch. You wouldnt get pip but you could swap between feeds fairly quickly. This is actually how we do it at work for a computer/security camera feed/computer/fee computer setup.

Comment: This is a good idea, but the solution should be strictly software-based.

Answer (score 1):

My hacky solution - change monitor A to one with PIP (picture-in-picture) and then get a Y-shaped video lead. No idea if such a thing exists or not.

If not, a port replicator style thing as is often used in electronics stores to demonstrate computer monitors should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) switch if I understand correctly.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is the viewing of multiple video ports/sources at the same time on one screen(like a pip setup or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Would it work to install [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) servers (essentially remote desktop) on all of the machines whose monitors you want to view, then run several instances of a VNC client on the monitoring computer? You might want to check out software like [VNC Thumbnail Viewer](http://thetechnologyteacher.wordpress.com/vncthumbnailviewer/) (I've never used it, but it looks nifty) which shows a thumbnail of each machine you have VNC running on, then you can click to enlarge the image.

Comment: That would work with a multiple-terminal system, but in this scenario, I'm thinking about one terminal with multiple monitors connected to it. I wonder if there's a vnc/rdp server(that you would run locally on the terminal) that would allow you to see the multiple monitor instances on the remote/client terminal(which would be itself).

Comment: Ok, I wasn't clear that it was all for the same machine. Hmm. I'll edit my post if I think of any other solutions.

Comment: Using the VNC approach, I got an approach working pretty well with TightVNC. I also made a guide for it. I'll add a new answer with the details. Thanks for your inspiration!